# Alternative to retainAll/removeAll for list of byte arrays?

Tags: java, list

I have two lists of byte arrays and I was hoping to use removeAll/retainAll to get some meaningful data but it doesn't seem to work. If I convert the byte arrays to strings first it does work as expected, but with the amount of data I am working with this is very expensive, especially considering I need to convert back to a byte array later. Is there an alternative to retainAll/removeAll that could be used without converting to a string first?

Comment: How about List<List<Byte>> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `retainAll`/`removeAll` does not work with arrays and works with `String`s is that strings compare for equality correctly, while byte arrays compare for identity equality.

Rather than converting to `String` and back, build a wrapper type around your byte array. Your wrapper needs to support `hashCode` and `equals` using the data in the array. Keeping these wrappers in the collection instead of the raw byte arrays would make your arrays comparable to each other, so `retainAll`/`removeAll` would work again.

```
class ByteArrayWrapper {
    private final byte[] data;
    private int hc;
    public ByteArrayWrapper(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
        for (int i = 0 ; i != data.length ; i++) {
            hc = 31*hc + data[i];
        }
    }
    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hc;
    }
    @override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof ByteArrayWrapper)) return false;
        ByteArrayWrapper other = (ByteArrayWrapper)obj;
        if (other.data.length != data.length) return false;
        for (int i = 0 ; i != data.length ; i++) {
            if (data[i] != other.data[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```